# How to create multi device uiautomator tests

Tags: android, android-studio, android-uiautomator

`uiautomator` tests are APKs which run internally to the device, thus I cannot write a test to support multiple devices.

I have found a few options

https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner

https://github.com/vidstige/UiMutilator/releases

https://sourceforge.net/projects/uiautomator/

Are there any better options or is this all there is? I'm not finding much out there.

I could use Appium, but I'm looking for a native API.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your tests locally on multiple devices by creating multiple instances of appium server. Every Appium server should be running on different ip and proxy address. So you should set your capabilities for each instance accordingly. But there is another solution as well but that's bit costly. That is **AWS Device Farm**. AWS provides multiple real devices hosted at there servers which you can use for executions of your customised test suits. They give initially 1000 free test minutes. You have to create a maven project for your test scripts. I prefer using **testng** rather than Junit.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that test app runs internally to device and can only instrument the device test app is running in.

I am adding a TCP server to the app and maybe creating a JSON protocol. This is similar to what most test client wrappers do I believe.